# Azure web aop High CPU Detected in Last 24 Hours

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

We have an azure app which unexpectedly shutdown for 5 to 10min several time  during mid night UTC. And every time we got the high CPU usage message in azure, where as we already stop a background service.

any suggestion ?

> High CPU usage was detected on 2 out of 3 instances. On those 2
>   instances, 'the application 'XXXXXX(production)'' was the main cause
>   of high CPU usage. Affected instances: RD0003FFXXXXE1, RD0003FFXXXX38

Comment: On the Azure SQL Database side are you seeing high DTU usage? The DTU graph on the portal is showing spikes?

Comment: yes but some time it only show web high cpu.

Comment: Well then the issue seems more related to the Web side. Anyway, enable Azure Automatic Tuning on the database side to allow the creation of indexes needed on the database side and lower CPU consumption on the database side. But you should focus on the CPU side.